# Hi Guys, I need a Wikihow functionality in my Magento site. Can anyone suggest an extension or a way to bring this up?

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I need a Wikihow functionality in Magento where the user or admin can include Step-by-Step Guides.
There is also similar iFixit website [iFixit](http://ifixit.com)